# Plot GeoDataFrame with multiple column attributes

Tags: python, geopandas

I'm using geopandas (python 3.8.2) to plot variables contained in a geodataframe.
I would like to plot on a single figure, all datasets with their own colormap.
The problem is that the plot shows only the last dataset, which corresponds to 'var_5' with colormap 'Reds'. Even if I set: ax = geodataframe.plot() it does not work.

Any idea ? Many Thanks!

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = 'myfile.geojson'
geodataframe = gpd.read_file(filename) 

cmaps = ['plasma', 'Greens', 'Blues', 'binary', 'Reds']
variables = ['var_1', 'var_2', 'var_3', 'var_4', 'var_5']

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (20, 10)
ax = plt.gca()

for i, var in enumerate(variables):
    geodataframe.plot(ax=ax, column=var, cmap=cmaps[i])

plt.show()
```

[image]

**Edit:**

After taking into account the answers, I got this image:
[image]

Comment: It looks like prev data is hidden behind the last plot. Please try `alpha=0.2` in the `plot`'s keywords to see if it changes something.

Comment: Hi Kate, thank you. Data are hidden at each loop. Setting the keyword actually changed the content of the dataframe and I am able to see all the variables.

Comment: `alpha=0.2` sets the transparency. Also, in the given plot, what output do you expect in case when two points overlap on the plot?

Comment: Also, if you don't want to plot white areas, you can use something like `geodataframe[geodataframe[var]>1].plot(ax=ax,column=var,cmap=cmaps[i])` (you may need to change 1 to the appropriate threshold)

Comment: Exactly! Normally the data are not supposed to overlap on the grid. But it still can happen depending on how they are constructed. If so, I have to calculate their contribution for each pixel (but that's my job :))

Comment: Can you describe exactly what you want to get? A clear goal would make my answer clearer.

Comment: Your answers were very clear to me and I have edited my post. My data set here consists of five classes, themselves made up of certain values ​​(not necessarily random).

For each class, I assign a color range, as if to classify them (but I am not applying any classification algorithm here).

I only displayed one class out of the five. By following your remarks, I manage to display all my classes.

Comment: Is the problem solved? If not, what adjustments do you wish to make? How would you like your final plot to look like?